# Is it possible to use wildcards within a Batch script to grab all directories under a path, and then use the relevant name for the creation of a file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, scripting

It's a bit of a convoluted title and I apologise for my poor English, it's not my first language and I'm far from fluent. I hope my current code explains my goal better than my written explanation.

```
@echo off
Setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set BCAT_PATH="C:\\Users\\USER\\Downloads\\FMOD conversion to packable\\0Tools\\bincat"
CD "9temp\\zzz_FSBS_Extract_test"
for /D %%D in (\*) do
"%BCAT_PATH%\\bincat" "%%D\*.ogg" -o "..\\zzz_BuiltOGG_test%%\~ni.tmp"
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
Setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set "BCAT_PATH=C:\Users\USER\Downloads\FMOD conversion to packable\0Tools\bincat"
CD "9temp\zzz_FSBS_Extract_test"
for /D %%D in (*) do FOR %%i in ("%%D\*.ogg") do ECHO "%BCAT_PATH%\bincat"  "%%i" -o "..\zzz_BuiltOGG_test\%%~ni.tmp"
PAUSE
```

Use `set "var1=data"` for setting string values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces. In comparisons; don't assign a terminal `\`, space or quotes - build pathnames from the elements - counterintuitively, it is likely to make the process easier.

Your `CD` statement will change to a directory **RELATIVE** to your current directory, so if you are currently at `C:\somewhere` to `C:\somewhere\9temp\zzz_FSBS_Extract_test`. If `9temp\zzz_FSBS_Extract_test` is an absolute location, then you'd need `\9temp\zzz_FSBS_Extract_test`

`for /D %%D in (\*) do` would set `%%D` to each directoryname in the root directory. Since you've changed to `..?..9temp\zzz_FSBS_Extract_test`, you need  `*` to scan the current directory. You could also use `"..?..9temp\zzz_FSBS_Extract_test\*"` without changing directory. *I don't know where `9temp\...` is, so I've used `..?..` to represent its location.

Note that the command to be executed must follow directly after the `do`, on the same physical line. I've added `ECHO` to show the command that would be executed. After you've verified that the command is correct, remove the `echo` keyword to actually execute the command.

Note that `BCAT_PATH` is set to `C:\Users\USER\Downloads\FMOD conversion to packable\0Tools\bincat` The command generated will thus be "C:\Users\USER\Downloads\FMOD conversion to packable\0Tools\bincat**\bincat**".

I've no idea where `%%i` is defined in your program. I've inserted it where I believe it should go. That should set `%%i` to each `.ogg` filename in the directory `%%D` in turn. `%%~ni` should return the name part of that file.

Your output directory would be `..?..9temp\zzz_BuiltOGG_test` since your current directory is `..?..9temp\zzz_FSBS_Extract_test` . The `\` should be placed between the directoryname and the filename.

Answer (score 0):

There is not need for `delayedexpansion` although `setlocal` is a good idea.

This will not do for each directory, but instead find each `.ogg` file recursively, then run the command on each file. Also note, I've added the `.exe` extension to `bincat`

```
@echo off
setlocal & set "BCAT_PATH=C:\Users\USER\Downloads\FMOD conversion to packable\\0Tools\bincat"
cd /d "9temp\\zzz_FSBS_Extract_test"
for /R %%i in (*.ogg) do "%BCAT_PATH%\bincat.exe" "%%~i" -o "..\zzz_BuiltOGG_test\%%~ni.tmp"
```